# react-native-video Error UI block RCTVideo 0x123e3f990

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I getting two error when I switch m3u8 link in iOS, Android Work Perfectly.

`Exception thrown while executing UI block: Cannot remove an observer <RCTVideo 0x123e3f990> for the key path "readyForDisplay" from <AVPlayerLayer 0x1c4625060> because it is not registered as an observer.`

`Exception thrown while executing UI block: 'parentNode' is a required parameter`

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/907), it has been fixed in the latest PR. Update your library.